# The specific elliptic fibration on the Kummer surface of the superspecial abelian surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves, birational-geometry, algebraic-surfaces

Consider two copies $E_1$, $E_2$ of the supersingular elliptic curve 
$$
y^2 = x^3 - 1\qquad (y^2 = x^4 - 1)
$$ 
over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ of odd characteristics $p$ such that 
$$p 
\equiv 2\ (\mathrm{mod}\ 3)\qquad (p \equiv 3\ (\mathrm{mod}\ 4)).
$$ 
In Katsura's article "*Generalized Kummer surfaces and their unirationality in characteristic p*" on 30 page it is stated that over the algebraic closure $\overline{\mathbb{F}_{p^2}}$ the Kummer surface $K = \mathrm{Kum}(E_1\times E_2)$ is birationally isomorphic to the elliptic surface
$$
y^2 = x^3 - t^4(t-1)^4\qquad (y^2 = x^3 - t^3(t-1)^3x).
$$
Is this true over $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$? How can I see this elliptic fibration on $K$? These particular questions are very important to answer the global one [Is there a purely inseparable covering $\mathbb{A}^2 \to K$ of a Kummer surface $K$ over $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/298995/is-there-a-purely-inseparable-covering-mathbba2-to-k-of-a-kummer-surface)